Are unconditional probability and conditional probability method necessary to generate the same result?
mcs.pdf shows 2 methods to calculate the probability of "switch wins" for Monty Hall problem.
unconditional probability (See Figure 17.5):

So we have the probability $\frac{1}{9}\cdot 6=\frac{2}{3}$
conditional probability (See 18.1 preface and 18.2.1. Here the book assumes these 2 probabilities must be same):

Something has gone wrong here, since we know that the actual probability of
winning by switching in 2/3.
In our initial description of the sce-
nario, we learned the location of the goat when Carol opened door B. But when we
defined our condition as “the contestant opens A and the goat is behind B,” we in-
cluded the outcome $(A, A, C)$ in which Carol opens door C! The correct conditional
probability should have been “what are the odds of winning by switching given the
contestant chooses door A and Carol opens door B.”

So the probability is $\frac{\text{Pr}[(C,A,B)]}{\text{Pr}[(C,A,B),(A,A,B)]}=\frac{2}{3}$

IMHO here the coincidence is due to the almost uniform Probability Space. (This is one contrived term. The second to last level of the tree has the uniform probability space and each subtrees rooted at one of The second to last level nodes are also the uniform probability space. So we say the last level of the tree has the almost uniform probability space.)
If we do the following contrived changes: $\text{Pr}[B,-,-]=0,\text{Pr}[C,-,-]=\frac{2}{3}$ (Here it means changing the level-1 probability of the tree in Figure 17.5), then unconditional probability is still $\frac{2}{3}$. But conditional probability becomes $\frac{\frac{2}{9}}{\frac{2}{9}+\frac{1}{18}}=\frac{4}{5}$.
Then when can we ensure unconditional probability and conditional probability method generate the same result? Does that include the above almost uniform Probability Space?

What is an “almost uniform probability space”?

@msantama Sorry for the ambiguity. This is my understanding the above probabilities. Leaf probability are either $\frac{1}{18}$ or $\frac{1}{9}$. This is one contrived term. I will update my question to say more.

In general, whenever you are able to distinguish a "conditional" probability from an "unconditional" probability, these two probabilities answer different questions and they will give the same answer only by coincidence.
In the case of the standard Monty Hall question, the sample space has three possibilities for the door initially chosen by the contestant. For each of those possibilities, there are two possible doors Carol can open. That gives us six different events to condition upon: the six ways the game can play out up to the point where the contestant has to make a final choice.
As it happens in the classic Monty Hall problem, the conditional probability of winning if the contestant switches is $\frac23$ in every one of those six possible events.
This assumes that the showrunners put the car behind a completely random door (equal probability for each door), that the contestant initially chooses a door completely at random, and that Carol opens each door with probability $\frac12$ when she can open either of the remaining doors (all of which probabilities are also assumed in the book's probability tree).
So if we assume that the contestant will "switch" no matter which of those events occurs, at the very start of the game we can project the contestant's probability of winning as follows:
\begin{align}
\Pr[\mathrm{win}\mid\mathrm{switch}]
&=        \Pr[(A,-,-)\mid(-,B,C)] \Pr[(-,B,C)] \\
&\qquad + \Pr[(A,-,-)\mid(-,C,B)] \Pr[(-,C,B)] \\
&\qquad + \Pr[(B,-,-)\mid(-,A,C)] \Pr[(-,A,C)] \\
&\qquad + \Pr[(B,-,-)\mid(-,C,A)] \Pr[(-,C,A)] \\
&\qquad + \Pr[(C,-,-)\mid(-,A,B)] \Pr[(-,A,B)] \\
&\qquad + \Pr[(C,-,-)\mid(-,B,A)] \Pr[(-,B,A)] \\
&= \frac23\cdot\frac16 + \frac23\cdot\frac16 + \frac23\cdot\frac16 + 
\frac23\cdot\frac16 + \frac23\cdot\frac16 + \frac23\cdot\frac16 \\
&= \frac23.
\end{align}
In other words, the unconditional probability is the weighted average of the conditional probabilities on all six branches up to the point just before the contestant makes a final choice.
It turns out that the unconditional probability is insensitive to the probability distribution of where the showrunners put the car and also insensitive to the probability distributions of doors that Carol opens in the three cases where she could open either of two doors.
An intuitive explanation for this (as explained in many other answers on this site) is that we can reasonably assume that the player originally has only a $\frac13$ chance of guessing the correct door on the first guess.
And the player wins by switching in every case where their first guess was wrong.
But as your "contrived" alteration of the classic assumptions shows, if we alter the showrunners' probability distribution we can alter the individual conditional probabilities among the six events. It turns out that if we alter Carol's probability distribution, that too can alter the individual conditional probabilities.
We will still come up with the unconditional probability $\frac23$ (assessed at the start of the game) for winning by switching, but that will come about by some of the conditional probabilities shrinking when other conditional probabilities grow.
The "coincidence" in the classic problem is that the probability distributions are so symmetric that all six possible paths up to the contestant's final choice give the same conditional probability of winning. The only way that a weighted average of six equal numbers can come out to $\frac23$ is if each of those numbers is $\frac23.$
But if you tweak the probabilities of the various branches in the probability tree, as you have seen, you can assemble the $\frac23$ weighted average from a list of different conditional probabilities.
If we unbalance the probability tree even further we can change even the unconditional probability. Suppose, for example, that $\Pr[(A,-,-)] = 1$ and that $\Pr[(-,A,-)] = 1,$
that is, the showrunners always put the car behind door A and contestants somehow always guess door A first. Then obviously $\Pr[\mathrm{win}\mid\mathrm{switch}] = 0.$
But this violates the intuition that the show should be set up so that the contestant only has a $\frac13$ chance of guessing the correct door the first time.


Thanks for your detailed description. The 1st paragraph shows we can't directly assume these 2 methods must have the same result except after some inspection we know that fact really holds. The exactly "when" question seems to be not easy to answer. 2. IMHO you may mean $$\Pr[\text{not win}\mid \text{switch}]=\Pr[(A,-,-)\mid(-,A,B)] \Pr[(-,A,B)]+\ldots=\frac13\cdot\frac16\cdot 6$$ Here I use Figure 17.5 tree.



To help future readers, the 2rd to 4th (up to "their first guess was wrong"), the 6th and the 8th paragraphs show why "unconditional probability" is always same when doing some kinds of changes to the probability distribution. The 5th paragraph shows the fact that "conditional probabilities" may be probably not that case. The 7th paragraph shows why the above coincidence occurs. The last paragraph shows "unconditional probability" may change under some contrived changes.


Thanks for spotting my mistaken use of the notation! Indeed $\Pr[(A,-,-)\mid(-,A,B)]$ is the conditional probability to lose by switching. For the probability to win, I needed $\Pr[(C,-,-)\mid(-,A,B)].$ I think I have fixed the inconsistency in the equation now.
